# Group by Time Span in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table structure:

```
ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
deviceID BIGINT NOT NULL,
entryTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
value FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
UNIQUE KEY (deviceID, entryTime)
```

I have about 15 million rows in this table and I want to fill another table with aggregated data from this table. I want to group this data by `deviceID` into "buckets" of size one day and take the min, max, and average of the values for that day. Any idea how I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,entryTime) [Date],
       deviceId,
       MIN(Value) MinValue,
       MAX(Value) MaxValue,
       AVG(Value) AvgValue
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,entryTime),
         deviceId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Convert(DATE, entryTime) as the select and group by clause, however if you wanted to group by more specific, or less specific time periods you'd use something like:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (deviceID, entryTime, min, max, avg)
SELECT deviceID, 
       DATEPART(yy, entryTime)+DATEPART(mm, entryTime)+DATEPART(dd, entryTime),
       MAX(value), 
       MIN(value), 
       AVG(value)
FROM OLD_TABLE 
       GROUP BY 
       deviceId, 
       DATEPART(yy, entryTime)+DATEPART(mm, entryTime)+DATEPART(dd, entryTime)
```